# Should I create a migration for a postgresql function in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, function

Should I create a migration for a postgresql function in rails?

How to make the migration and how to call the function?

I have this:

```
class CreateReportFunction < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SPROC
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reporter
        ...
     SPROC
  end
end
```

Then I made a rake:db, but how do I know this worked fine? How can I use the function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should and providing a `down` method it's even more lovely (to rollback in case).

It works fine because otherwise Postgresql will raise an error which activerecord will wrap in `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid`, which in turn will make the migration fail and won't be considered as executed.